How to derive a type based on an object keys?
I need to derive a type ColorVariant from PALETTE object. The expcected result is:
type ColorVariant = "common.black" | "common.white" | "primary.25" | "primary.50" | "primary.100" | "error.25" | "error.50" | "error.100" | "success.25" | "success.50" | "success.100"

Actual result is:
type ColorVariant = never

Code:
const PALETTE = {
  common: {
    black: "#000",
    white: "#fff",
  },
  primary: {
    25: "#FAFAFF",
    50: "#F5F5FF",
    100: "#E7E7FC",
  },
  error: {
    25: "#FFFBFA",
    50: "#FEF3F2",
    100: "#FEE4E2",
  },
  success: {
    25: "#F6FEF9",
    50: "#ECFDF3",
    100: "#D1FADF",
  },
} as const;

export type Colors = keyof typeof PALETTE;
export type ColorOptions = (typeof PALETTE)[Colors];
export type Tone = keyof ColorOptions;

export type ColorVariant = `${Colors}.${Tone}`;

I do understand that this happens because of different keys in common and primary, error, success...unfortunately I do not undetstand how can I fix it. Please help
Here's TS playground

Does this approach meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

@jcalz yes, that's it! Can you explain how this works please?

You need to actually iterate over every key K in keyof Palette and for each such key compute the template literal type `${K}.${keyof Palette[K]}`, and then compute the union of all of those.  You can do this with a  mapped type over keyof Palette which you then index into with keyof Palette.
That's called a distributive object type as coined in microsoft/TypeScript#47109, which looks like {[K in KK]: F<K>}[KK]} when you have a keylike union KK and a type function F<>.  It distributes the F<> type function over unions in K.  So if KK is K1 | K2 | K3, then  {[K in KK]: F<K>}[KK] is F<K1> | F<K2> | F<K3>.
Conceptually for ColorVariant it would look like
type ColorVariant = { [K in keyof Palette]:
  `${K}.${keyof Palette[K]}` // error!
}[keyof Palette];

But there's a wrinkle where the compiler fails to notice that keyof Pallete[K] is always serializable via template literal types.  A keyof operator can produce any PropertyKey, which is string | number | symbol.  But only string | number are serializable, and symbol is not.  So you need to Exclude symbol from the result of keyof for the compiler to be sure it's acceptable:
type ColorVariant = { [K in keyof Palette]:
  `${K}.${Exclude<keyof Palette[K], symbol>}`
}[keyof Palette];

And that becomes
/* type ColorVariant = "common.black" | "common.white" | 
        "primary.25" | "primary.50" | "primary.100" | 
        "error.25" | "error.50" | "error.100" | 
        "success.25" | "success.50" | "success.100" 
*/

as desired.
Playground link to code
